# mongodb system current date (yyyy-mm-dd)

Tags: mongodb, sysdate

i wanna extract data in MONGODB from a collection only for the current day .
i've tryed this request:

```
db.hello.aggregate([
    { $match: { "name": "btb" } },
    { $where: function() { 
        today = new Date(); 
        today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        return (this.date.getTimestamp() >= today)
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: { articles: "$articles" },
        total: { $sum: 1 }
    }},
    { $project: {
        "articles": 1,
        "total": 1
    }},
    { $sort: { "total":-1 } }
])
```

but i got that message error:

```
####################################################################

Unable to execute the selected commands

Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 16436: 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$where'' on server localhost:27017. 

The full response is:
{ 
    "ok" : 0.0, 
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$where'", 
    "code" : NumberInt(16436)
}

####################################################################
```

Comment: ***i wanna extract data in MONGODB for the current day like for today: 26-07-2018, i've tryed this request:***  can you please explain bit more

Comment: @rayane-btb can you provide more details (like sample documents and expected result)?

Comment: wanna have a result from mongodb where the field date match the current day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
db.collection.find({ createdAt: { $lte: new Date() , $gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 18)} })`
```

18 minutes ago (from now)

Answer (score 0):

I usually fetch data like that :

```
db.mycollection.find(
 { "createdAt" : 
  {
   "$gte" : new Date("2013-10-01T00:00:00Z"),
   "$lt" : new Date("2013-10-02T00:00:00Z") }
 })
```

`$gte` for greater then 
`$lt` for less then

Comment: I finaly used this solution and it works for me:
{date_field : { "$gte": new Date(new Date().getTime()-(1000 * 60 * 18))}}